# Parsing command to Powershell (quotation marks)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to run this command within command prompt but it doesn't work due to the quotation marks.  I've tried various alternatives but now am stuck.

```
powershell -command "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name -notlike "*store*"} | Remove-AppxPackage"
```

Would really appreicate some advice.
Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Simply wrap the quotation marks in quotation marks. Sounds and looks funny but works.Or use single quotation marks inside instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes around your name filter can be escaped using `\`

```
powershell -command "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name -notlike \"*store*\"} | Remove-AppxPackage"
```

Line can be pasted in a batch script (.bat) or just run from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

An APOSTROPHE rather than a QUOTATION MARK can be used.

```
powershell -command "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | where-object {$_.name -notlike '*store*' } | Remove-AppxPackage"
```

Please note that the capital letters are not being used to yell. They are the Unicode character names. https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Comment: In what way does it "not work?" Is there an error message? Does it just not find any items to remove? Check to see if there are any items to remove using `powershell -command "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '*store*' }"`

Comment: I'm very sorry.  It does work. I tried it again on a clean install and it works.

Comment: Previously the command would ignore keeping the windows store app and proceed to remove all apps inc store.

Comment: @Boyd, thank you for letting me know. I would suggests that the different quoting would be better than introducing escape characters.  There is such a mix of escapes available. \", "", ^", and in PowerShell, `".

Comment: understood. Appreciate the advice.